# How to get the rootweb object from a subweb in SP 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I want to get the `RootWeb` object from my sub web object using PowerShell.

```
$site=  get-spsite "http://srvr1:123/sites/ceo"
$rootwebb=  $site.RootWeb
$suburl= get-spweb "http://srvr1:123/sites/ceo/hr/policies"
$subweb= get-spweb $suburl
#how to get the  rootweb object from $subweb ?
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean, a site collection has a root web. A web is by definition a web so it has no root web. By getting $subUrl you are getting that web there is no further root. Maybe if you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 14):

You can use

```
$SubWeb.Site.RootWeb
```